# Create one .so file from code in two sub-directories

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, shared-libraries

I need to create a `.so` file on Linux Ubuntu 13.10 so I could wrap with Python (but I am pretty new to cmake).

I have in my directory `wrap`/

```
map.h
map.cpp

/noise 
  /include
  /src

/noiseutils
  noiseutils.h
  noiseutils.cpp
```

`noise` is a directory with `include` and `src` directories in and `noiseutils` has `noiseutils.h` and `noiseutils.cpp` files inside.

Can anyone help me to create a `.so` file with cmake — I am very new to C++?

Comment: You compile all the .cpp files using `g++` then link them together (again, using `g++`). If this doesn't help, then google "compiling C++ code tutorial".

Comment: @H2CO3 I think question is not about just making library, but about how to do it in cmake: [tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html), [library](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:add_library)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `add_library` command in your CMakeLists.txt configuration file. Here is the current command reference: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:add_library

Notice the second option after the library name can be 'SHARED', giving your .so file on Linux.

The directory layouts of your sources is not important; you just need to provide the relative path to the .cpp file from the CMakeLists.txt (e.g., noise/src/noise.cpp). And also make sure any directories containing .h files are included using the `include_directories` command.